# Get a HBITMAP from an 24bit BMP file loaded into memory

Tags: winapi, bitmap

I have a 24bit BMP file loaded into RAM and I'm trying to create a HBITMAP for this image file.  I have found some examples around which I've been experimenting with, but can't seem to make work.  Basically, I need a HBITMAP for the file, so that I can unload the file and just keep the HBITMAP which I can dispose of later with DeleteObject().  Since this bitmap is loaded very early on in my application, there is no application Window and therefore no HDC.  This is what I have so far:-

```
HBITMAP cBitmap;  // This should be where my bitmap handle ends up.
mem;              // This is a void* pointer to the loaded BMP file


tagBITMAPFILEHEADER bfh = *(tagBITMAPFILEHEADER*)mem;
tagBITMAPINFOHEADER bih = *(tagBITMAPINFOHEADER*)(mem + sizeof(tagBITMAPFILEHEADER));
RGBQUAD rgb = *(RGBQUAD*)(mem + sizeof(tagBITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(tagBITMAPINFOHEADER));

BITMAPINFO bi;
bi.bmiColors[0] = rgb;
bi.bmiHeader = bih;

UINT8* pixels = mem + bfh.bfOffBits;
void* ppv;
HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateDIBSection(NULL, &bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, &ppv, NULL, 0);
SetDIBits(NULL, hBitmap, 0, bih.biHeight, pixels, &bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
GetObject(hBitmap, sizeof(BITMAP), &cBitmap);
```

For some reason that just baffles me, cBitmap ends up being NULL.  And another thing that puzzles me...  DIB_RGB_COLORS means that the BITMAPINFO has a pointer to literal RGB values, but how does that work with a 24bit image, which doesn't have a palette?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um, that's not how `GetObject` works. The usage is

```
GetObject(handle, sizeof(object), &object);
```

In your case, the expectation is that you call it as

```
BITMAP bitmap;
GetObject(hBitmap, sizeof(BITMAP), &bitmap);
```

You are not passing a pointer to a `BITMAP` structure, so the behavior is undefined.

You don't need `GetObject` at all. You already have your `HBITMAP`. It's in the `hBitmap` variable.

```
cBitmap = hBitmap;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are loading a file from disk, it's probably easiest to use `LoadImage()` with the `LR_LOADFROMFILE` flag.

To create a `HBITMAP` from file data that has already been loaded into memory, you can do something similar to the following:

```
HBITMAP ConvertDibToHBitmap(void* bmpData)
{
    HBITMAP hBitmap = NULL;
    BOOL success = FALSE;

    // NOTE: Assumes the BITMAPFILEHEADER is present (not normally the case for
    // an in-memory DIB)
    LPBITMAPFILEHEADER bfh = (LPBITMAPFILEHEADER) bmpData;
    LPBITMAPINFOHEADER bih = (LPBITMAPINFOHEADER) (bfh + 1);
    void *pixels = (char*) (bih + 1); // NOTE: Assumes no color table (i.e., bpp >= 24)

    HDC hdc = GetDC(NULL);
    if (hdc != NULL) {
        hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, bih->biWidth, bih->biHeight);
        if (hBitmap != NULL) {
            HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
            if (hdcMem != NULL) {
                HBITMAP hOldBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcMem, hBitmap);
                if (StretchDIBits(hdcMem, 0, 0, bih->biWidth, bih->biHeight,
                        0, 0, bih->biWidth, bih->biHeight, pixels,
                        (LPBITMAPINFO) bih, DIB_RGB_COLORS, SRCCOPY) > 0)
                    success = TRUE;

                SelectObject(hdcMem, hOldBitmap);
                DeleteDC(hdcMem);
            }
        }

        ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);
    }

    if (!success && hBitmap != NULL) {
        DeleteObject(hBitmap);
        hBitmap = NULL;
    }

    return hBitmap;
}
```

Comment: Hi...  thanks for the answer, but you must have missed some important points in my question.  Firstly, the Bitmap is already loaded into memory and can't be loaded with LoadImage/LoadBitmap() because it is a .bmp file that's embedded in a binary blob of data.  I extract the .bmp file from this binary blob of data and need to create a HBITMAP from it.

Secondly, as I stated, creating the HBITMAP is done VERY early in the startup of my application, so there *IS NO* Window or HDC, so using GetDC() and things like that can't be used as there is no application Window at this time.

Comment: I listed two approaches.  If `LoadImage()` does not work in your situation, then use the second approach.  Even if you don't have an application window, you can still use `GetDC(NULL)` to get a device context for the screen (desktop window actually).  So, this should work fine for your case.