# Can't properly load bitmap from the memory

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, bitmap

**Brief introduction** to the problem:
I got the **zip archive**, where the set of files in the **bmp format** are placed.
I wan't to **load bitmaps from that archive** (create system objects) and pass their **HBITMAP to a client** method which will display it on the screen.

I tried 2 ways to solve my task:
1) **using temporary file** (this methods works fine, but I think that it is **inefficient** - as requires additional actions on file creation and requires that user posses some privileges that allows him to create files)

```
hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, fullpath.c_str(), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE | LR_DEFAULTCOLOR | LR_CREATEDIBSECTION );
```

2) **unzipping the needed file to the memory and using the memory buffer for bitmap creation**
(My solution is based on the information from the similar questions on SO and other sources)

```
BITMAPFILEHEADER* bmfh = (BITMAPFILEHEADER*)ibuf;
BITMAPINFOHEADER* bmih = (BITMAPINFOHEADER*)(ibuf + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));
BITMAPINFO* bmi = (BITMAPINFO*)bmih;
void* pBMPdata = (void*)(ibuf + bmfh->bfOffBits);
hBitmap = CreateDIBitmap(NULL, bmih, CBM_INIT, pBMPdata, bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
```

**I need help on the 2-nd way.**
When image is loaded from the HBITMAP obtained on the second method - black square is displayed/

**UPDATE:**
I tried **3-rd method:**

```
BITMAPFILEHEADER* pBmfh = (BITMAPFILEHEADER*)ibuf;
BITMAPINFOHEADER* pBmih = (BITMAPINFOHEADER*)(ibuf + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));
BITMAPINFO* pBmi = (BITMAPINFO*)pBmih;
void* pBMPdata = (void*)(ibuf + pBmfh->bfOffBits);
void* pToFill = 0;
hBitmap = CreateDIBSection(NULL, pBmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, &pToFill, NULL, NULL);
```

**Result:** is black square, which has dimensions of the picture I am trying to load.

Any ideas that might help are appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried passing a valid device context handle?

Comment: Maybe you should, the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183491%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) doesn't suggest you can pass an invalid / NULL.

Comment: @DyP I figured out that is the problem, and it isn`t related to the DC

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15127010/420683

Comment: @ Jonathan Potter char *ibuf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be helpful for others how may encounter this issue(**black square which has dimensions of the image you are trying to load**).

**3-rd method works.**

```
BITMAPFILEHEADER* pBmfh = (BITMAPFILEHEADER*)ibuf;
BITMAPINFOHEADER* pBmih = (BITMAPINFOHEADER*)(ibuf + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));
BITMAPINFO* pBmi = (BITMAPINFO*)pBmih;
void* pBMPdata = (void*)(ibuf + pBmfh->bfOffBits);
void* pToFill = 0;
hBitmap = CreateDIBSection(NULL, pBmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, &pToFill, NULL, NULL);

memcpy(pToFill, pBMPdata, pBmfh->bfSize - pBmfh->bfOffBits); // this line should be added!!
```

My mistake was, that I was trying to pass pointer to pointer to the databits, instead of it
**I should after invokage copy databits to the void** (which is pToFill).**